# How to send PRBS pattern from sfp+ transceiver?

Tags: ethernet

I have a compliance board for SFP+ transceivers. For CFP2 transceivers there is some integrated PRBS pattern generator, but I can't find something similar for SFP+ transceivers.
Is this even possible using the compliance board alone or do I need an AWG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send anything you want from an SFP+ module - it doesn't care what you feed it.

You need to turn on the laser and then feed a differential signal to pins 18 and 19. Check [SFF-8418](https://members.snia.org/document/dl/25879) for details.

Comment: I should have clarified, I would like to skip an AWG and write the desired pattern somewhere on the EEPROM of the transceiver. Is this possible? I've been told that there should be some registers reserved for that, but I can't find the address.

Comment: That isn't possible - there's nothing in an SFP module that could generate that signal. I don't know about your compliance board but you'll need some kind of generator - doesn't need to be a real AWG.

Comment: Thank you,  I accepted your answer. Can't upvote unfortunately due to reputation :/

Comment: Do you happen to know whether that's valid for a QSFP module as well? I can't seem to make this one emit light. We do have an AWG.

Comment: The SFP interface and functionality is largely the same for all derivatives (SFP+, QSFP, SFP-DD, ...), differing only in the number of lanes basically. You always need some kind of external signal generation, there's nothing integrated.